# How to add button to Google Play store in bottom corner of Android App?

Tags: java, android, xml, button, layout

I'm putting together a simple Android app and I wanted to add a button to one of the bottom corners of the screen that when the user presses brings them either to the app's GooglePlay page or my GooglePlay profile page (whichever way I decide before hand).

After doing some searching on a guide for doing this I found this link below which basically shows what I want and gives some script for doing it, the problem is I'm not exactly sure which file I need to place this script and where in it exactly, do I put this script somewhere in the AndroidManifest.xml file ? The layout main.xml ?

http://www.appsgeyser.com/blog/tag/customized-code/

Any help would be appreciated I'm new to this Android App stuff.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to add a [Button](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html) to your layout which should contain the Button. In your case it's main.xml from the layout folder. Then your main.xml should look similar to this one:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

 <!--other Views-->

 <Button
     android:id="@+id/button"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
     android:layout_margin="8dp"
     android:text="My Apps" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

In your MainActivity you assign an [OnClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html) to this Button:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             //open up browser or play store with the provided link
            String url = linkToYourDeveloperPage;
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent); 
        }
    });
}
```

Inside onClick you create an [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) with an url which shows your developer page or your apps in the Play Store.

If you'd like to have an image rather than just text, you can also use [ImageButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html).

Comment: Thanks for the reply Antict ! This is what I was looking for, just need a little help on a couple of things. Where exactly do I paste that first button code at in the Main.xml you listed to get this button to be in the bottom right corner of the App? I placed it at one spot and it works but it's around the middle of the app screen.                                                                                     Then also when you say "In you MainActivity"  your talking about the MainActivity.java file right ?

Comment: *Update* I have like the bottom last 1/6th of my app screen dedicated to Admob banners I was hoping I could somehow have this button sit on that section and then when the Admob banners show up they cover it till the ad is closed or whatever. But it seems I can only put this button just over that section or just under (which I'm doing right now). But the button stays on the bottom left corner of the screen and visually would look better if it were middle aligned would I be able to do that ?

Comment: I have figured out how to place the button in the main.xml file for the most part. But I don't have a clue where to place the onclick code above in the MainActivity.java file. Any help with that ?                                                      And do I replace the text "linkToYourDeveloperPage" with just an URL ?

Comment: I have been trying to post the onclick code in at different spots in the MainActivity.java but it always fails to compile.

Comment: Yes, you just use an URL, the code should then look similar like this one: `String url = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=gamertrail1"`. Maybe you can post your MainActivity.java and your main.xml code, so I can try to find the problem.

Comment: Make sure, that in your main.xml the id "button" is only used once. Then in your MainActivity.java you create a Button and you reference the Button in your layout. This is what the first line `Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button)` does, make sure `setContentView(R.layout.main`) is called before. After you created that Button, you can assign the OnClickListener and handle clicks.

Comment: Ok here is a dropbox link to my MainActivity file (before pasting any of this code above in) - > https://www.dropbox.com/s/t8t2j584qv3f5x1/MainActivity.java?dl=0

Comment: And here is my Main.xml file with the button code already in from my original post >>> https://www.dropbox.com/s/8g8v7dfluxjsbuz/main.xml?dl=0

Comment: You have to do all this layout stuff in your AbstractMainActivity. There you'll find `setContentView(R.layout.main)` which sets main.xml as your layout in which you can search for ids. Then you can use `findViewById(...)` for your ads and the button.

Comment: Yesterday I was messing around with my AbstractMainActivity before you made this post but I couldn't figure out how to get it working. Could you maybe explain exactly where to paste this code. And when you say "do all this layout stuff in your AbstractMainActivity" do you mean the part of the code from @Override down ? I will post a link to my Abstract file too https://www.dropbox.com/s/wi7twy5mxq7rb5r/AbstractMainActivity.java?dl=0

Comment: OK I FINALLY FIGURED IT OUT!!! LOL Just kept studying the code and trying to learn more about java and to see what I wasn't understanding. Also one of the things I needed to add was a couple imports for the Intent and Uri.                                                                                                                     Well thanks for all the help Antict, hopefully you won't hear from me again but there is a good chance I will be back to Stackoverflow to ask some more questions haha. Peace bro